# Probability for an $n\times n$ matrix to have only real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix where every entry is i.i.d. and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. What is the probability that $A$ has only real eigenvalues?

The answer cannot be $0$ or $1$, since the set of matrices with distinct real eigenvalues is open, and also the set with distinct, but not all real, eigenvalues is open (the matrices with repeated eigenvalues have measure zero).

I don't see any easy transformation that links the two sets, and working on the characteristic polynomial seems quite impractical. Also, I have the feeling that $[0,1]^{n^2}$ is not a good space to work in, due to its lack of rotational invariance.

Comment: From here: http://web.math.princeton.edu/mathlab/projects/ranmatrices/yl/randmtx.PDF
 following the proof of Theorem 1, you might be able to find the distribution in terms of the distribution of traces. If you can't follow their method with complex numbers directly, maybe defining $A_+=A+A^*$ and $A_- = i(A - A^*)$ (both of which have real eigenvalues) could work.

Comment: @SamJaques they are dealing with symmetric matrices, and they work for big $n$.. Are you sure?

Comment: I'm not sure it will work, no. On a second look it seems like a key component of the argument for higher moments is that $\sum_{j=1}^N(A^2)_{jj}=\sum_{j,k=1}^N(A_{jk})^2$ which requires symmetric matrices.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to say something about the distribution of the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Degree_3) of the characteristic polynomial

Comment: I'm curious why the set of matrices with distinct real eigenvalues is open (I'm assuming as a subset of the $n \times n$ real matrices.)

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg the eigenvalues of a matrix are the roots of the characteristic polynomial, and the roots are continuous functions of the coefficients

Comment: @Exodd Yes, indeed! But $\mathbb{R}$ is not open as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. How can you complete your argument?

Comment: I guess to clarify, I certainly agree that within the set of matrices with real eigenvalues, those with *distinct* eigenvalues is an open set. But that is relatively open, in the sense that $(0,1)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ but not in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @AdinaGoldberg We are on the set of real matrices, so the eigenvalues are either real or come in couples of conjugated complex numbers. If you have distinct real eigenvalues, then you can always find a small enough neighbourhood where the eigenvalues are not complex due to the continuity of the eigenvalues

Comment: Empirically : $3$: $0.708$, $4$: $0.346$, $5$: $0.117$

Comment: It should be a coincidence, but the desired probability seems to be quite near the probability of an $n-1 \times n-1$ random _gaussian_ matrix having all real eigenvalues
$$\begin{array}
n & & \\
2  &1      &   1 \\   
3 &0.708  &   0.70711\\
4 &0.346  &   0.35355\\
5 &0.117 &    0.125\\
6 & 0.028   &  0.03132\\
\end{array}
$$
Left column: empirical. Right column: from here: https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82140233.pdf

Comment: @leonbloy how many examples have you generated for the empirical evaluation?

Comment: about one million (trusting Octave's random generator)

Comment: with 10kk the results do not change much...

Comment: This paper: https://shub.ccny.cuny.edu/articles/1994-how_many_eigenvalues_of_a_random_matrix_are_real.pdf says:Mehta [24, Conjectures 1.2.1 and 1.2.21 conjectures from extensive numerical
experience that the statistical properties of matrices with independent identically distributed entries behave as if they were normally distributed as n -+ rn .
Mehta focuses on the symmetric or Hermitian cases, but surely the idea is quite
general.

Comment: @leonbloy That is quite feasible: If we pick one (probably existing) real eigenvector and take it to $e_n$ via an orthonormal base change, the other entries in the resulting matrix are essentially linear combinations of a large number of iid uniform random variables, so by the law of big numbers are gaussian. Well, the independence is a bit hand-wavy as the original eigenvector depends on all entries and vice versa all entries in the new matrix are influenced by the eigenvector. *(cont.*)

Comment: @leonbloy *(cont.)* Then again, the "large amount of independence" from originally $n^2$ random values has to be "squeezed" into $(n-1)^2$ random values. So they are certainly independent indeed. Admittedly, this is still in a typical [what could possible go wrong?](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatCouldPossiblyGoWrong) scenario.

Comment: just a quick thought. Assume $n=2$. If $A$ eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ is complex, then $A-\lambda_2 I $ cannot be drawn as a parallelogram in, say $XY$ plane i.e. its area (in $XY$ plane) does not exist. Since the number of eigenvalues increases as $n\rightarrow \infty$, it feels for sure that at least for one of them, say $\lambda_n$, the $n$-dimenional area $det(A-\lambda_n I)$ does not exist. Thus the sought probability is $0$.

Comment: Since this question is getting a lot of attention, I ask you to reformulate it. Every square matrix has at least one complex eigenvalue, since every polynomial of degree $\geq 1$ has at least one complex root (note that real numbers are also complex numbers, by definition). What you ask is the probability for all eigenvalues to be real. Right?

Comment: @iljusch done, thanks

Comment: My intuition is that the probability is zero, and that intuition is based on a slightly simpler problem: Consider the set of n x n matrices where all eigenvalues satisfy $|\lambda| < 1$. The subset of these matrices where all eigenvalues is real is a set of subset of measure zero relative to the entire set in eigenspace. I would expect something similar if you change the constraint from the one I suggested to the original problem, but I'm not sure what the mapping from n x n matrices with entries all in [0, 1] "looks like" in eigenspace, so that's where my intuition might fall apart.

Comment: @AdamCataldo the probability Cannot be zero, since the set of all-real eigenvalues matrices has non-empty interior part. Your reasoning holds if you consider complex-entries matrices, while here we have only real entries

Comment: Not sure I follow this, because what I'm saying is that in the unit circle in the complex plane, the real line, that is the real values between -1 and 1, has measure zero. It does in fact have an empty interior, because if you draw a ball of any radius around any of the points on the real line, the ball will include complex numbers, not just real values.

Comment: @AdamCataldo if the eigenvalues of the matrices were "continuously" distributed in the unit circle, then you would be correct. But if you take real matrices, the distribution of their eigenvalues is biased on certain areas of the unit circle, and in particular they greatly concentrate on the real line, so much that even if $[-1,1]$ is negligible in the unit circle, the probability of having real eigenvalues is not zero

Comment: I think what I'm stuck on is measure space you're trying to work in, since you're suggesting in the problem it shouldn't be $[0, 1]^{n^2}$ (presumably with Lebesgue measure). It sounds like it's also not the eigenspace (the subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is projected on by the set of matrices in $[0, 1]^{n \times n}$). Or do you think the projection into the eigenspace is such that the eigenvalues on the real line have non-zero measure?

Comment: @AdamCataldo yes, if you only consider real matrices then the eigenvalues are very biased towards the real line. Maybe finding a bigger space where to work may not be a bad idea, but the choice of the biger space has to reflect/expand somehow consistently the properties of the spectra of real matrices

Comment: The probability the matrix is symmetric is zero, but maybe one can argue that a certain class of “almost symmetric” matrices (via a perturbation) have real eigenvalues and with positive probability, to get a lower bound on the desired probability in question.