# Probability of all eigenvalues being real for a random matrix

Tags: random-variables, random-matrices

For a large real-valued random matrix, eigenvalues follow the [circular law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_law), but for small matrices, there's a preference towards the real line. How can I upper bound this probability?

[image]
For instance suppose $M$ is a $d\times d$ matrix with IID Gaussian entries with mean 0 and variance $1/d$, here are sample probabilities :

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  & \text{d} & \text{p(real)} \\
  & 2 & 0.7146 \\
  & 3 & 0.3553 \\
  & 4 & 0.1184 \\
  & 5 & 0.0351 \\
  & 6 & 0.0052 \\
  & 7 & 0.001 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

```
fractionReal[d_] := (numSamples = 10000;
   mat := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[d]], {d, d}];
   mats = Table[mat, {numSamples}];
   evals = Eigenvalues /@ mats;
   allReal[list_] := AllTrue[list, RealValuedNumberQ];
   N@Mean[Boole[allReal /@ evals]]);
TableForm@Table[{d, fractionReal[d]}, {d, 2, 7, 1}]
```

```
d = 2;
numSamples = 10000;
mat := RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[d]], {d, d}];
mats = Table[mat, {numSamples}];
evals = Eigenvalues /@ mats;
ComplexListPlot[Flatten@evals, 
 PlotLabel -> "evals of 2x2 random matrices", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re", "Im"}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.5], PointSize[Medium]]]
```

Comment: I think this is related. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372115/random-matrices-having-all-real-eigenvalues-uniform-vs-gaussian-distributions

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3770846/probability-for-an-n-times-n-matrix-to-have-only-real-eigenvalues